# Convert Log file to Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have log files, which have many lines in the form of :

`<log uri="Brand" t="2017-01-24T11:33:54" u="Rohan" a="U" ref="00000000-2017-01" desc="This has been updated."></log>`

I am trying to convert each line in the log file into a Data frame and store it in csv or excel format. I want only values of **uri**, **t** is nothing but time **u** for **username** and **desc** for **description**

Something like this

Columns :-  `uri      Date      Time       User   Description`

```
        Brand  2017-01-24   11:33:54  Rohan   This has been updated.
```

and so on.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup to parse and extract data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by @*Corralien* in the comments, you can use some of [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) functions ([`Beautifulsoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=beautifulsoup()#beautifulsoup) and [`find_all`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all)) to parse each line in your logfile separately, then use [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with a *listcomp* to make a DataFrame for each line :

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 #pip install beautifulsoup4
​
with open("/tmp/logfile.txt", "r") as f:
    logFile = f.read()
​
soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(logFile, "html5lib")
​
dfList = [pd.DataFrame([(x["uri"], *x["t"].split("T"), x["u"], x["desc"])],
                        columns=["uri", "Date", "Time", "User", "Description"])
           for x in soupObj.find_all("log")]

#this bloc creates an Excel file for each df​
for lineNumber, df in enumerate(dfList, start=1):
    df.to_excel(f"logfile_{lineNumber}.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output :

```
print(dfList[0])

     uri        Date      Time   User             Description
0  Brand  2017-01-24  11:33:54  Rohan  This has been updated.
```

Update :
*If you need a single dataframe/spreadsheet for the all the lines, use this :*

```
with open("/tmp/logfile.txt", "r") as f:
    soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, "html5lib")

df = pd.DataFrame([(x["uri"], *x["t"].split("T"), x["u"], x["desc"])
                   for x in soupObj.find_all("log")],
                  columns=["uri", "Date", "Time", "User", "Description"])

df.to_excel("logfile.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: How can I store the whole logfile in a single excel sheet. Above for loop creates new excel for every new line in log file

Comment: I thought that is what you expect. I updated my answer so you can store all the lines in one single Excel spreadsheet ;)

Comment: Hello @Timeless, Thank for the help. Facing one more issue as you updated the code I am getting only header in xlsx file. 
`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [uri, Date, Time, User, Description]
Index: []`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Working fine on a .txt file (having no header) with two lines/logs.